# how to show field name if it set to true

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the 'ContentSubCategory' name.its fields are like below:

```
Id                  int 
FaName              nvarchar(50)    
IsSpecial           bit 
IsPerishable        bit 
IsDanger            bit
```

now I Want a query that shows list of content names and the attributes that are set to True.
for example:

```
Row          ContentInfo
------------------------------------
1            animal - IsSpecial
2            Human Body - IsSpecial,IsPerishable
3            Danger Goods - IsSpecial,IsDanger
```

how can I do that?

Comment: Please try something first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select cast(FaName as varchar)+' - '+cast( 
case when IsSpecial = 1 then 'IsSpecial,' else '' as varchar)+cast(
case when IsPerishable = 1 then 'IsPerishable,' else '' as varchar)+cast(
case when IsDanger = 1 then 'IsDanger' else '' as varchar)
from your_table
```

Try this and adjust to your own like.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `STUFF()`:

```
SELECT
    FaName
    ,ISNULL(
        NULLIF(
            STUFF(
                CASE WHEN IsSpecial = 1 THEN ', IsSpecial' ELSE '' END
                + CASE WHEN IsPerishable =1 THEN ', IsPerishable' ELSE '' END
                + CASE WHEN IsDanger = 1 THEN ', IsDanger' ELSE '' END
            , 1, 2, '')
        ,'')
    , 'Unknown')
    As Class
    FROM TableName
```